# SQL Join two tables by unrelated date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m looking to join two tables that do not have a common data point, but common value (date). I want a table that lists the date and total number of hired/terminated employees on that day. Example is below:

Table 1

```
Hire Date   Employee Number   Employee Name
--------------------------------------------
5/5/2018         10078          Joe
5/5/2018         10077          Adam
5/5/2018         10078          Steve
5/8/2018         10079          Jane
5/8/2018         10080          Mary
```

Table 2

```
Termination Date    Employee Number   Employee Name
----------------------------------------------------
  5/5/2018                10010         Tony
  5/6/2018                10025         Jonathan
  5/6/2018                10035         Mark
  5/8/2018                10052         Chris
  5/9/2018                10037         Sam
```

Desired result:

```
Date    Total Hired Total Terminated
--------------------------------------
5/5/2018      3             1
5/6/2018      0             2
5/7/2018      0             0
5/8/2018      2             1
5/9/2018      0             1
```

Getting the total count is easy, just unsure as the best approach from the standpoint of "adding" a date column

Answer (score 2):

If you need all dates within some window then you need to join the data to a calendar. You can then left join and sum flags for data points.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = (SELECT MIN(ActionDate) FROM(SELECT ActionDate = MIN(HireDate) FROM Table1 UNION SELECT ActionDate = MIN(TerminationDate) FROM Table2)AS X) 
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = (SELECT MAX(ActionDate) FROM(SELECT ActionDate = MAX(HireDate) FROM Table1 UNION SELECT ActionDate = MAX(TerminationDate) FROM Table2)AS X) 

;WITH AllDates AS
(
    SELECT CalendarDate=@StartDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, 1, CalendarDate) 
    FROM AllDates 
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, CalendarDate) <= @EndDate
)


SELECT
    CalendarDate,
    TotalHired = SUM(CASE WHEN H.HireDate IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 1 END),
    TotalTerminated  = SUM(CASE WHEN T.TerminationDate IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 1 END)
FROM
    AllDates D
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 H ON H.HireDate = D.CalendarDate
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T ON T.TerminationDate = D.CalendarDate
/* If you only want dates with data points then uncomment out the where clause
 WHERE
    NOT (H.HireDate IS NULL AND T.TerminationDate IS NULL) 
*/
 GROUP BY
    CalendarDate
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a `union all` and aggregations:

```
select dte, sum(is_hired) as num_hired, sum(is_termed) as num_termed
from (select hiredate as dte, 1 as is_hired, 0 as is_termed from table1
      union all
      select terminationdate, 0 as is_hired, 1 as is_termed from table2
     ) ht
group by dte
order by dte;
```

This does not include the "missing" dates.  If you want those, a calendar or recursive CTE works.  For instance:

```
with ht as (
      select dte, sum(is_hired) as num_hired, sum(is_termed) as num_termed
      from (select hiredate as dte, 1 as is_hired, 0 as is_termed from table1
            union all
            select terminationdate, 0 as is_hired, 1 as is_termed from table2
           ) ht
      group by dte
     ),
     d as (
      select min(dte) as dte, max(dte) as max_dte)
      from ht
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte), max_dte
      from d
      where dte < max_dte
     )
select d.dte, coalesce(ht.num_hired, 0) as num_hired, coalesce(ht.num_termed) as num_termed
from d left join
     ht
     on d.dte = ht.dte
order by dte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT ISNULL(a.THE_DATE, b.THE_DATE) as Date, 
    ISNULL(a.Total_Hire,0) as Total_Hire, 
    ISNULL (b.Total_Terminate,0) as Total_terminate
FROM (SELECT Hire_date as the_date, COUNT(1) as Total_Hire 
    FROM TABLE_HIRE GROUP BY HIRE_DATE) a
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT Termination_Date as the_date, COUNT(1) as Total_Terminate 
        FROM TABLE_TERMINATE GROUP BY HIRE_DATE) a
    ON a.the_date = b.the_date
```